# How to use string resource in switch statement

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, switch-statement

Is there a way to use a string resource with a switch statement? After trying to obtain a string resource programmatically, an error is returned.

**Error**

> 'resourceLoader' is variable but is used like a type

**C#**

```
public class PageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

        Type page = null;
        switch (value as string)
        {
            case resourceLoader.GetString("SteveJohnson/Text"):
                page = typeof(FirstPage);
                break;
            case resourceLoader.GetString("PeteDavidson/Text"):
                page = typeof(SecondPage);
                break;
            case resourceLoader.GetString("OneDrive/Text"):
                page = typeof(FistPage);
                break;
            case resourceLoader.GetString("Twitter/Text"):
                page = typeof(SecondPage);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return page;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, they must be compile-time constants. Looks like you could use a `Dictionary<string, Type>` instead.

Comment: I think you've got a typo; `fistPage` to `firstPage` ?

Comment: @CodeCaster: _"they must be compile-time constants"_ -- this used to be the case, but no longer. It's unfortunate that the author of this question did not spend time researching before posting, but it is true that existing Q&A on SO about the limitations of `switch` have largely been invalidated by recent features added to C#, i.e. pattern-matching, which take away the blanket prohibition against non-constant expressions for `case` statements.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I did do research before asking this question but didn’t find the relevant sources. d219 gave an answer but the code returns a warning.

Comment: _"I did do research"_ -- Part of the "research required" research is that the question must explain what research has been done, what you found, what of the research helped and why the rest did not. Naturally this doesn't have to be 100% exhaustive, but it _must_ include enough information so that people can understand what you already know and what you need help with. If the question doesn't actually share evidence of the research done, you might as well not have done it as far as the SO community is concerned.

Comment: _"d219 gave an answer but the code returns a warning"_ -- yes, that's true. A warning that is _trivial_ to solve, by casting `value` in the case statement, or in the switch statement, or by using the `object.Equals()` method instead of the `==` operator. In any case, it seems that the author of that answer has addressed the warning (not in an ideal way IMHO but at least it should work).

Comment: @Peter I know I'm getting old and can't keep up with all the changes to C#... But I knew about pattern matching. But look at the answer. Using a discard, always true label and then filtering using `when`, and calling `resourceLoader.GetString()` in each label.... It's just frigging ugly and not what pattern matching is meant for, just to shoehorn it into a switch?

Comment: @CodeCaster: yeah, I don't dispute your complaints about that answer. But it does seem to literally accomplish what was asked. And honestly, without having more context from the OP, it's not clear whether a dictionary-based approach would really be more readable. That said, my only point was to correct the notion that in today's C#, `case` statements are required to use only constant expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a step back and look at *why* you want a switch statement: probably to have a readable block of code. You could easily do the same with a couple of `if()`s:

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

Type page = null;
if (value == resourceLoader.GetString("SteveJohnson/Text"))
    page = typeof(FirstPage);
else if (value == resourceLoader.GetString("PeteDavidson/Text"))
    page = typeof(SecondPage);
else if (value == resourceLoader.GetString("OneDrive/Text"))
    page = typeof(FistPage);
else if (value == resourceLoader.GetString("Twitter/Text"))
    page = typeof(SecondPage);      

return page;
```

Now you could rewrite this using [pattern `when` clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions) to shoehorn it into a switch, but I don't think that's the appropriate construct here, as it doesn't really increase readability. You could opt for a Dictionary with options instead:

```
var pageTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { resourceLoader.GetString("SteveJohnson/Text"), typeof(FirstPage) },
    { resourceLoader.GetString("PeteDavidson/Text"), typeof(SecondPage) },
    { resourceLoader.GetString("OneDrive/Text"), typeof(FirstPage) },
    { resourceLoader.GetString("Twitter/Text"), typeof(SecondPage) },
};

// Defaults to `null` when not mached
pageTypes.TryGetValue((string)value, out Type page);
return page;
```

You could even cache the resource lookups by initializing this dictionary once, for example in the constructor of the containing class.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)? It's only something I've found recently (it's a C# 7 feature [which I came across in this link](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx)) and what you're doing is a little different from the use case I had but I've just run a quick test with pseudo code (calling a method of another class which takes and returns a string from the `switch` statement) which seemed to work. For what you're doing I think you'd have something like this:

```
switch (value)
{
    case string _ when (resourceLoader.GetString("SteveJohnson/Text") == value as string):
                    page = typeof(FistPage);
                    break;
    case string _ when (resourceLoader.GetString("PeteDavidson/Text") == value as string):
                    page = typeof(SecondPage);
                    break;
```

Comment: A warning is returned: `Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side type to 'string'`

Comment: Hmm, potentially you need to `ToString()` the value you are using for the switch? (test code I wrote is on other laptop but have made an edit above, see if that works, if not I'll have another look tomorrow - it's assuming the `ToString` of the object is what you need to do the comparison on of course).

Comment: After trying `ToString()` the warning is still there

Comment: OK fired up the other laptop as couldn't see why there'd been a problem - I skim read your message above and thought it was an error, now I realise it's a warning (as you said) have corrected by moving your original `as string` into each case statement; that gets rid of the warning :)

Comment: Also replaced the variable name I had before with the discard `_` as you don't need to do anything with that return value.